# Xampp keeps redirecting to dashboard

Tags: apache, xampp

I am trying to set up local dev environment with virtual host, using XAMPP, on my new work laptop - running Windows 10.

I have exactly the same set up as on my Surface Pro where it works, but each time I try to access local, I get redirected to the dashboard.

In the hosts file I have added:

`127.0.0.1  local.testing.co.uk`

In **httpd-vhosts.conf** I have added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/www/testing-co-uk/web"
ServerName local.testing.co.uk
 <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In **httpd.conf**, I have amended the DocumentRoot and Directory as follows:

`DocumentRoot "C:/www"
<Directory "C:/www">`

My testing-co-uk folder is in C:/www

- If I go to local.testing.co.uk, I get redirected to local.testing.co.uk/dashboard.
- If I go to localhost, I also get redirected to local.testing.co.uk/dashboard.
- If I go to localhost/index.php, I do get to the front page of site I want, however clicking on a link will take me to local.testing.co.uk/linkname (and a 404 error).

Can anyone kindly suggest what could be going wrong? I have been going slowly insane for about 10 hours now.  I have checked various other posts within Stack Overflow and tried various solutions, and of course, restarted Xampp every time.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Kind regards
James